# Powering a T5 bulb with a battery?

Tags: light

Would this be possible, and how would I go on about it? I'm really sorry, I'm stuck and I couldn't fine anything online that could help me, I know absolutely nothing about this.. It is a 4W T5.

Comment: What battery? Can it even deliver 4 W?

Comment: Get one of these, take it apart and you have your 4 W T5 driver: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1nM0jRXXXXXa3XVXXxh4dFXXXs/Smuxi-Portable-Ultraviolet-Lamp-2in1-Flashing-Torch-Blacklight-UV-Light-Tube-Bulb-Handheld-Money-Detector-Battery.jpeg

Comment: Look for ST micro Application Note ELECTRONIC FLUORESCENT LAMP BALLAST
by  A. Vitanza, R. Scollo, and A. Hayes.
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/43/99/f4/24/48/d7/41/7f/CD00003901.pdf/files/CD00003901.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003901.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Sure,  I used to own a battery operated flourescent lamp.

you can still buy some eg:

http://www.directindustry.com/industrial-manufacturer/fluorescent-flashlight-108961.html

but most people prefer LEDs these days.

If you really want to do this you need an inverter power-supply that produces a few hundered volts... perhaps you could use a laptop backlight inverter.